# PHP site to angularjs site redirect with hashbang

Tags: php, angularjs

I am redirecting from my old domain in php to new domain built in angularjs(with hashbang #!). i have set up the redirect in the .htaccess file and the redirect works fine. But php replaces the has with %23. So the path is not recognized by the angularjs views config. How can i overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `.htaccess` file to see if it has a No Escape flag.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

It looks like the rewrite rule is escaping the hash.